# Trying to get a working launch.json configuration for remote debugging of Arm application

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, remote-debugging

I have remote debugging working using gdb-multiarch from a terminal on my local x64 linux machine.  Can view source, set breakpoints on the target just fine.

I'm trying to get a working launch.json configuration that will work so I can use VSCode to make things easier.

I've looked at various ones on line, and found one example that is close but I'm having one issue where it whines about the Working Directory.

I've tried different variants but either I get the pop-up about the working directory or file not found.  Or another error about a null reference.

The initial example looked like it used the path to the project directory on the local machine but different variations on specifying the path didn't work.

I've tried setting "cwd": to /home/root which is currently where the target executable lives on the ARM box.  But that didn't correct the issue either.

I'm probably missing something obvious but I'm not seeing it.

Here's the launch.json as it currently sits:

==== launch.json ====
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

```
    {
        "name": "Debug",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb-multiarch",
        "targetArchitecture": "arm",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/arm/debug/noAPI",

        "setupCommands": [
        {
            "text": "file ${workspaceFolder}/arm/debug/noAPI"
        },
        {
            "text": "target remote localhost:3333"
        },
        {
            "text": "monitor reset init"
        }

        ],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
]
```

}

Would like to get remote debugging working in VSCode.
With the current launch.json I get the following error in the Debug Console:
Stopping due to fatal error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I add any existing directory to cwd: I get that same failure.  The original example launch file appeared to specify a file in the cwd string which seemed strange but doing that gives a pop up message:
launch: workingDirectory 'path name' does not exist, which makes sense since it appears to really want a directory path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a remote ssh extension to help.

Comment: Thanks but from the description that doesn't look like it would work in this particular remote setup.  What I wound up doing that works great is switch to CLion for remote debugging.  That was trivial to set up and get working in my environment.  For this project VS Code is easier to use for building since we already have cross build Makefiles setup, and CLion primarily uses CMake for building.  But for remote debugging CLion is working much better.